# Spinner в ActionBar

Tags: android, android-spinner, actionbar, android-menu

Необходимо разместить `Spinner` в `ActionBar`. Пользователь будет выбирать в `spinner` пункт и в активити будет отображаться список. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно разместить его в `ActionBar`?

Создала меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="Выберите фильтр"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

В классе так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        spinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.dropdowm, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

А как реализовать выбор пункта из спиннера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно вы добавили спиннер, у него насколько я понял не должно быть никакого id и в xml активности его тоже нету. Добавляется он так:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.android_action_bar_spinner_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_list_item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return true;
    }
```

а дальше уже у вас получается простая менюшка, в которой можно добавить слушатель для spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("spinner", "on item selected");
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

и все будет так как вам нужно. Вот [первоисточник](https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/how-to-add-spinner-dropdown-list-to-android-actionbar-toolbar.html) и как [добавлять](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22901703/9363441) слушатель. То есть если по сути - у вас просто другое отображение меню тулбара будет и все. [Вот](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2018/07/android-toolbar-action-bar-and-menu.html) еще полезная ссылка может пригодится.

Comment: А есть пример как реализовать слушатель? Первая ссылка из вашего ответа я по ней и пыталась сделать, но вот со слушателем возникла проблема.

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна, обновил ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста. Это изначально обычный спиннер, то есть слушатель подойдет и тот который используется для обычного спиннера в активности

Comment: Разобралась, спасибо.. Нужно было имплементировать интерфейс слушателя.